# c# Collapse and flatten list of nested payments in object list

Tags: c#, arrays, json, linq, sorting

I have a (simplified) database schema for payments:

ID / Name / Payment / ParentPaymentId

When a payment fails and i "retry" i create a new payment and set its parent as the previously "failed" payment.  This means i can see the history of each payment and the previous attempt.  If the subsequent payment fails another payment is then created and the ParentPaymentId is again set to the last attempted payment (and so on)

When trying to display a list of payments (some which succeeded / some needed n number of retrys) i would like to view the most "current" payments and the child payments need to be in a single secondary heirachy.

e.g.
Database

```
ID / Name / Payment / ParentPaymentId
1    Jan     100          NULL
2    Feb     100          NULL
3    Mar     100          NULL
4    Mar(r)  100          3
5    Mar(r)  100          4
6    Mar(r)  100          5
7    Mar(r)  100          6
8    Apr     100          NULL
```

From the above you can see that ID 7 is the MOST recent attempt at trying to bill the March Payment

How can i get this List<> array (already in EF c#) into an object graph like so.

```js
[  
   {  
      "Id":"1",
      "Name":"Jan",
      "Payment":"100"
   },
   {  
      "Id":"2",
      "Name":"Feb",
      "Payment":"100"
   },
   {  
      "Id":"7",
      "Name":"Mar(r)",
      "Payment":"100",
      "Payments":[  
         {  
            "Id":"6",
            "Name":"Mar(r)",
            "Payment":"100"
         },
         {  
            "Id":"5",
            "Name":"Mar(r)",
            "Payment":"100"
         },
         {  
            "Id":"4",
            "Name":"Mar(r)",
            "Payment":"100"
         },
         {  
            "Id":"3",
            "Name":"Mar",
            "Payment":"100"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "Id":"8",
      "Name":"Apr",
      "Payment":"100"
   }
]
```

Comment: I would create a separate grouping table for grouping rather than the recursive parent->parent->parent thing. You’re saving space (which you don’t need to conserve so aggressively) and table design effort (the last thing to economize on) at the expense of having a weird kludge in your code. Don’t ask SQL to be something it’s not, if there’s a clean and conventional way to get the job done.

Comment: "Simplified database schema" you are saying, but this is not a simplified schema. In a simplified schema you would simply have something like a rootId that groups all those Mar payments (say rootId = 3).

Comment: I mean i have simplified MY schema rather than show all my columns..

Comment: You want two different types of objects, one with a `Payments` field and one without in the same structure? And what is `[]` and `{}` supposed to represent?

Comment: @NetMage It's JSON.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I know, and that helps with defining C# data structures how?

Comment: @NetMage So you're saying you do know what those symbols represent? Array, object? Do you think JSON might be a serviceable and widely understood shorthand for describing an object graph?

Comment: No, I do not, because in C# you shouldn't have entries with varying fields in a single (`Array`? `List`? `IEnumerable`? some other Collection object I should guess?) collection.

Comment: @NetMage How did you determine that it's an absolute requirement in this case to model "no children" with a near-duplicate class that lacks a child collection, rather than with an instance of the same class that happens to have an empty collection? Can you share your reasoning?

Comment: Lack of any sort of Payments: [] or Payments: null in the objects without children implies to me the field doesn't exist - why should I guess what it should be? OTOH, a `List<PaymentWithChildren>` from my answer would be clearer.

Comment: @NetMage If OP thinks he needs two classes, he's mistaken and it's your job to suggest that he only needs one class. He's asking the question. He knows he's not happy with what he's got. Sensible questioners (most of them, including me) are almost always happy if you can suggest a cleaner solution that gets around the problem entirely.

Comment: @NetMage But I don't think he does want two classes. You *did* guess. It's ambiguous, and you made an assumption that he wants a bad design. The only fully sane way to code the classes he implied is one class with a potentially empty collection. If you're willing to go halfway sane, the one with the child collection could inherit from the childless one (but I don't think you can do that in EF, so never mind). Your answer almost seems deliberately perverse.

Comment: @EdPlunkett My answer only uses one class so I am not sure what you are on about?

Comment: @NetMage I'd hope you'd be at least as familiar with the code in your answer as I am.

Comment: @EdPlunkett So what are the two classes that represent the answer in my code?

Answer (score 1):

I defined some classes to represent the data since you didn't:

```
public class PaymentClass {
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    public double Payment;
    public int? ParentPaymentId;
}

public class PaymentWithChildren {
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    public double Payment;
    public int? ParentPaymentId;
    public PaymentClass[] Payments;
}
```

If you setup a mapping to retrieve payments by ID, you can then create a helper to return the parents:

```
public static class PaymentHelpers {
    public static Dictionary<int, PaymentClass> PaymentMap;
    public static void SetupPaymentMap(PaymentClass[] db) {
        PaymentMap = db.ToDictionary(p => p.ID);
    }
    public static PaymentClass PaymentForID(int anID) => PaymentMap.TryGetValue(anID, out var p) ? p : null;

    public static IEnumerable<PaymentClass> Parents(PaymentClass[] db, int id) {
        var p = PaymentForID(id);
        while (p.ParentPaymentId.HasValue) {
            p = PaymentForID(p.ParentPaymentId.Value);
            yield return p;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can call the setup/helper methods with some LINQ:

```
PaymentHelpers.SetupPaymentMap(db);
var parents = db.Where(p => !db.Any(p2 => p2.ParentPaymentId == p.ID));
var parentsWithChildren = parents.Select(p => new PaymentWithChildren {
    ID = p.ID,
    Name = p.Name,
    Payment = p.Payment,
    Payments = PaymentHelpers.Parents(db, p.ID).ToArray()
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your example, you have these payments (the last number is the parent payment. -1 means no parent):

```
1,Jan,100,-1
2,Feb,100,-1
3,Mar(r),100,-1
4,Mar(r),100,3
5,Mar(r),100,4
6,Mar(r),100,5
7,Mar(r),100,6
8,Apr,100,-1
```

Start by creating a dictionary keyed by payment id, that contains the parent id and a child id that's initially set to -1. You end up with:

```
1, {-1, -1}
2, {-1, -1}
3, {-1, -1}
4, {3, -1}
5, {4, -1}
6, {5, -1}
7, {6, -1}
8, {-1, -1}
```

Now, iterate over the keys of the dictionary and for each entry that has a parent id, look up that parent node and link its child id to the current entry. You end up with:

```
1, {-1, -1}
2, {-1, -1}
3, {-1, 4}
4, {3, 5}
5, {4, 6}
6, {5, 7}
7, {6, -1}
8, {-1, -1}
```

Finally, go through that dictionary one more time. Any entry that has a child of -1 is a completed payment, and you can follow the parent links backwards to get the history.

Answer (score 0):

When the question is "How do I do perform some strange gyrations to reconstruct a simple relationship that was known at some point in the past?", the answer is "fix the design so the relationship is expressed in a simple and straightforward way". I see this as an X/Y question.

Payment table:

```
ID / Name / Payment / PaymentGroupID
```

PaymentGroup table:

```
ID / InitialPaymentID
```

When a payment fails, create a PaymentGroup record. ID is autonumbered. Set InitialPaymentID in the new record to the ID of the payment that failed, and set that payment's PaymentGroupID to the new PaymentGroup.ID.

Here's an alternative solution, in one table:

```
ID / Name / Payment / InitialPaymentID / ParentPaymentID
```

ParentPaymentID is what it was before. InitialPaymentID is the ID of the payment that failed. This gives you something sensible to select on. I chose to set InitialPaymentID to 3 on item 3, the one that failed, because at first glance I think that would be useful. But I might change that decision during development.

```
ID / Name / Payment InitialPaymentID / ParentPaymentId
1    Jan    100     NULL               NULL
2    Feb    100     NULL               NULL
3    Mar    100     3                  NULL
4    Mar(r) 100     3                  3
5    Mar(r) 100     3                  4
6    Mar(r) 100     3                  5
7    Mar(r) 100     3                  6
8    Apr    100     NULL               NULL
```

I'm going along with your "simplified schema" approach: Naturally, in a real database these tables would have lots of other columns. But this is the essence of it.